# how to call mongodb server side function inside mapReduce in java

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, mapreduce

i have stored two functions in the "system.js" collection named "mapfun" and "reducefun" and i am trying to call those function from java. i am trying to call these function through MapReduceCommand. i am not able to call these functions. can anyone please help me with this.
the two function looks like this
//mapfun

```
{ "_id" : "mapfun","value" : { "code" : "function(){var criteria; if(this.speed > 70 ){ criteria="overspeed";emit(criteria,this.speed); } }" } }
```

//reducefun

```
{ "_id" : "reducefun", "value" : { "code" : "function(key,speed){ var total=0; for(var i=0;i<speed.length;i++){ total=total+speed[i]; } return total/speed.length; }" } }
```

and my mapreducecommand looks like this

```
MapReduceCommand command=new MapReduceCommand(collection, map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);
MapReduceOutput output=collection.mapReduce(command);
```

i have passed the map and reduce function as strings in which i have called the mapfun and reducefun respectively
 and it looks like this

```
String map = "function (){var x=mapfun();"
                + "return x;};";
```

```
String reduce = "function(key, speed) {var y=reducefun(key,speed);"
                + "return y;};";
```

what am i doing wrong here and how to correct this kindly help me with this.

Comment: The `this` context might be changing when you call the stored function.  Try having the map function accept an argument, and call it like `var x=mapfun(this)` to make sure it's seeing the right information.

Comment: the map function takes the current collection only

Comment: The function you've stored in system.js is an ordinary function that you are calling from within the map function.  Pass that function the current `this` when you call it, to make sure it is evaluating the object you think it is.  If it is getting a new `this` context when you call it, then `this.speed` will always be undefined, and nothing will ever be emitted.

Comment: so what to pass as an arguement collection name ?

Comment: In the map function, pass `this`.  In the stored function, give it a named argument, and use that name like you would have used `this`

Comment: it works when i tried to execute it from the mongodb shell and it also works when i pass the whole map function as a string in the MapReduceCommand  constructor, but when i stored it in the server then the problem arises i guess the problem lies in the way of calling those functions, that's what i am stuck with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem is that the `this` variable is reassigned for each function call.

To demonstrate, I ran a short test from the mongo shell.

Fist create a collection containing 1 document:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.maptest.find({},{_id:0})
{ "canary" : "tweet" }
```

Then create a stored function that will take an argument emit 2 values, one using `this` and one using the passed argument:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.system.js.find()
{ "_id" : "testfun", "value" : { "code" : "function(arg){emit(\"this.canary\",this.canary),emit(\"arg.canary\",arg.canary)}" } }
```

Then use the stored function in a mapReduce call:

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.maptest.mapReduce(function(){testfun(this)},function(a,b){return {a:a,b:b}},{out:{inline:1}})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "arg.canary",
            "value" : "tweet"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "this.canary",
            "value" : undefined
        }
    ],
...
```

As you can see, `this.canary` was undefined, but `arg.canary` contained the value from the input document.

The mapReduce framework assigns `this` to the document currently being examined when calling the map function.  When the stored function is called from within the map function it gets its very own `this`.  However, by calling the function as `testfun(this)` the original `this` context of the map function is provided to the stored function as an argument.